# Составление SQL запроса на удаление в связанных таблицах

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Есть три таблицы: company (компания), department (отдел), subdivision (подотдел). Прошу помочь написать запрос следующего вида: удаляем компанию "Копыта" с id = 2, раз компании такой больше нет, то соответственно удалить отделы содержащие id_company = 2, а у каждого удаляемого отдела, удалить все подотделы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понял как удалять из связанной таблицы, например `DELETE FROM Department WHERE id_company = 2`, а как мне удалить тогда подотделы (subdivision) удаляемых отделов?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Company" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "name_company"  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Department" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "id_company"    INTEGER,
    "name department"   TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Subdivision" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "id_department" INTEGER,
    "name_sub"  TEXT
);
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (1,'Рога');
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (2,'Копыта');
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (3,'Енот');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (1,2,'Отдел копыт');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (2,1,'Отдел рогов');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (3,3,'Енотный отдел');
INSERT INTO "Subdivision" VALUES (1,1,'Рога и нетолько');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: А почему не хотите удалить тремя куда более простыми запросами, если трудности в написании одного? Это учебное задание? И ещё вопрос. Эти таблицы связаны друг с другом через foreign key?

Comment: + Было бы здорово, если бы вы скинули код для создания и заполнения этих таблиц.  Тогда бы вам быстрее помогли.

Comment: Можно, лишь бы работало))) Ну как учебное, сам книжку читаю сам себе придумываю, т.е. четкого задания как в универе нет. У меня в голову не укладывается вот что: например есть индекс удаляемой компании - "2" и из таблицы Company "Копыта" я удалил. Поскольку значение id осталось, то в табл. Department я могу написать: DELETE FROM Department WHERE id_company = 2, а как мне в таблице subdivision (подотдел) узнать что я должен удалить? Там получается надо знать id_department который попал под удаление...

Comment: Кода нет. Я их руками сделал в DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Если есть foreign keys, то вам дам дали ответ куда смотреть. Если стоит в настройках внешних ключей каскадное удаление - то всё произойдёт автоматом https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: DB Browser не пользовался, но обычно в инструментах есть экспорт таблиц. Для SO подойдёт экспорт в DDL.

Comment: DDL не нашел. Есть файл в базу в файл SQL.. А там вот такой код. Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используются
каскадные удаления по Foreign key:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Company" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "name_company"  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Department" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "id_company"    INTEGER,
    "name department"   TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_companies
    FOREIGN KEY (id_company)
    REFERENCES Company(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Subdivision" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "id_department" INTEGER,
    "name_sub"  TEXT,
     CONSTRAINT fk_departments
    FOREIGN KEY (id_department)
    REFERENCES departments(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (1,'Рога');
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (2,'Копыта');
INSERT INTO "Company" VALUES (3,'Енот');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (1,2,'Отдел копыт');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (2,1,'Отдел рогов');
INSERT INTO "Department" VALUES (3,3,'Енотный отдел');
INSERT INTO "Subdivision" VALUES (1,1,'Рога и нетолько');
COMMIT;
```

На выходе имеем каскадное удаление. Код для проверки:

```
select * from Company c
left join Department d on c.id = d.id_company
left join Subdivision s on s.id_department = d.id

;
delete from Company where id = 2
;
select * from Company c
left join Department d on c.id = d.id_company
left join Subdivision s on s.id_department = d.id
```

Всё это можно посмотреть здесь:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rxrd88bNJL7S1uAhcJ4Up6/1

Comment: Спасибо! Так вроде все понятно) Не могли бы вы прокомментировать строчку "CONSTRAINT fk_companies", откуда она взялась и что делает? Я прочитал что это какое-то ограничение... Но не пойму как оно появилось и что делает?

Comment: Это вы должны писать самостоятельно. Создается констрейнт (ограничение). Ему присваивается имя (любое допустимое) fk_companies. В данном случае при его создании создаём внешний ключ, ссылающийся на уникальный идентификатор в другой таблице. Указываем, что В нашей таблице ссылки на другую содержаться в поле id_company. И указываем на какую таблицу и какое поле ссылаемся. Лучше прочтите в интернете про эти понятия - Primary key, foreign key, unique index.

Answer (score 1):

Если каскадное удаление не установлено, то можно получить Id, которые надо удалить, из подзапроса:

```
DELETE FROM Subdivision 
WHERE id_department IN (
    SELECT id FROM Department WHERE id_company=2);
```

Вот в [песочнице](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rxrd88bNJL7S1uAhcJ4Up6/1)

Comment: Спасибо большое!  Этот вариант мне очень нравится)

Answer (score 0):

Если таблицы связаны между собой, то на мой взгляд проще включить каскадное удаление[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Замените, пожалйста, картинку командой на изменение таблицы в текстовом виде.